# Multiple align points and multiple equations

Tags: math-mode, align

I have 2 equations, both have to be numbered and aligned. Equations' numbers should be vertically centered. But equations are long and have to be broken into 2 or 3 lines each. It would be great to have 2 alignment points in each line. But I cannot achieve that using `split`. Or can I?  Here is the MWE:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
z_1^{i,j}
    & = a_1 \, x_1^{i,j} + b_1 \, \delta_1^{i,j} \\
    & + \sum_k y_k^{i,j} \qquad \forall ~i,j
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
z_2^{i,j}
    & = a_2 \, x_2^{i,j} + b_2 \, \delta_2^{i,j} + c_2 \\
    & + z_1^{i,j} \qquad \forall ~i,j
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Basically, I want the same output as produced with this code, especially equations' numbers vertically centered. In addition, I want `\forall ~i,j` from both equations to be also aligned, *i.e.* below each other. Solution with `alignat` instead `align` would be even better for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're using a two column format.

The environment `split` only accepts one alignment point; you can use `\mathmakebox` from `mathtools` (that also loads `amsmath`) and `calc`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
z_1^{i,j}
    & = a_1^{} x_1^{i,j} + b_1^{} \delta_1^{i,j} \\
    & \qquad+ \sum_k y_k^{i,j}
      \qquad \forall i,j
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
z_2^{i,j}
    & = a_2^{} x_2^{i,j} + b_2^{} \delta_2^{i,j} + c_2^{} \\
    & \qquad + \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle\sum_k y_k^{i,j}$}][l]{z_1^{i,j}}
      \qquad \forall i,j
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\,` between factors is not used, while `^{}` is recommended in order to push subscripts at the same level. The `+` on the second line shouldn't be under the equals sign, as it belongs to the right hand side of the expression.

[image]

However, the subscripts are not really level, because of `j` at the exponent, so you might want a slightly more complex adjustment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\adjs}[1]{^{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
z_1^{i,j}
    & = a_1\adjs{j} x_1^{i,j} + b_1\adjs{j} \delta_1^{i,j} \\
    & \qquad+ \sum_k y_k^{i,j}
      \qquad \forall i,j
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
z_2^{i,j}
    & = a_2\adjs{j} x_2^{i,j} + b_2\adjs{j} \delta_2^{i,j} + c_2\adjs{j} \\
    & \qquad + \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle\sum_k y_k^{i,j}$}][l]{z_1^{i,j}}
      \qquad \forall i,j
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works nice. It's very elegant solution and just what I wanted. And the \adjs command is just beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no problem with each of your equations in one line, and the `∀` symbols can be aligned with the `alignat` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
z_1^{i,j}    & = a_1 \, x_1^{i,j} + b_1 \, δ_1^{i,j}
     + ∑_k y_k^{i,j} &  \qquad &  ∀ ~i,j \\
z_2^{i,j}
    & = a_2 \, x_2^{i,j} + b_2 \, δ_2^{i,j} + c_2
     + z_1^{i,j}  &  &  ∀ ~i,j
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]